# What if I don't want to do a PhD but my professor says I have to else he will not let me graduate. What should I do?

Tags: thesis, masters

I just want to do a master's and that's it, I don't want to do any more schooling, tertiary education is awfully tiring because you have to work and study at the same time. I know this seems like a whining complaining about bachelor's degree. I can't wait to leave academia.

Actually, I'm a college senior anxious about my future, I don't want to do a PhD. After looking at these theses I'm not sure if I can handle a PhD anymore. I'm not doing a PhD due to intense stress.

Comment: It's not like they can force you to commit to a PhD in writing. If you have to lie a bit to get your papers, that seems like a small sacrifice compared to the coercion they are putting you under.

Comment: At my university, a student is able to submit his/her thesis without his/her supervisor's approval.   Look up your university's policy.

Comment: @tripleee I don't want to do a phD how to lie?

Comment: Tell them you will do what they want but then don't.

Comment: It might help to get a more complete answer if you provided a little more context.  Was this an actual threat to your graduation? Or did they just say something like it would be a shame to waste your talent?

Comment: @DarkerSapo4 It might help to say something about the country or continent where your institution is located. I know some standard answer in NA/Europe, but it might not generalize past that.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close for now; this could be an interesting question, but we're going to need more details about what exactly was said. Is he threatening to block your bachelors degree? Why can't you just ignore him and sign up for a masters program somewhere else?